# Big Query pviot or nested for table in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, pivot-table

Hi checking if anyone can advise on pivot table here . Im thinking should i use pivot function or nested function .
Any advise on how to go about this ?

This is what i have

[image]

And i would like to SQL code it to

[image]

To show only 1 student_id and gender (since they are repeated data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input table is already pivoted, so you can make it as a nested table using **ARRAY_AGG()** AND **GROUP BY**.

```sql
SELECT student_id, gender, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(course, monday, tuesday, wednesday)) courses
  FROM pivoted_table
 GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Jaytiger for your sharing . It works for me but now i have to think of ways to reduce my query run . I have more columns and it is taking up alot of query bytes